# How to print printable characters and characters like '\n', '\t', etc

Tags: c, printing

I'm trying to display an HTTP frame. The problem is that some characters are not recognized. I use the isprint function.

Here is the function I created:

```
void printAscii(const int dataLength, const char *data){
  if (dataLength <= 0) {
    printf("No data (data length <= 0)\n");
  } else {
    printf("Warning: Unsupported characters are not displayed.\n\n");
    size_t i;
    printf("|- ");
    for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
      if (isprint(data[i])) {
        printf("%c", data[i]);
      }
      if (data[i] == '\n') {
        printf("|- ");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that characters like "\ n" and "\ t" are not displayed either. 
I thought of adding additional conditions in my function

```
  if (isprint(data[i]) || data[i] == '\n' || data[i] == '\t')
```

But I was wondering if there was not a more "clean" way?
I started the C there is not too long so do not hesitate if I made mistakes in my function.

### EDIT

I may not have been clear enough in my question.

My project is a frame analyzer (pcap), and I get to the HTTP part. The frame contains only ASCII, so it is relatively easy to display this type of frame. The problem is that some characters are not displayed directly (encoding for images for example) so I decided to ignore these characters. The problem is with isprint () characters like '\ n', '\ t', etc ... are not displayed either and so my display is less "beautiful".

For example, this HTTP trame :

```
<ul>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
</ul>
```

become :

```
<ul><li>Foo</li><li>Bar</li></ul>
```

which is less understandable.

### Edit 2

I found. This code works as desired.

```
  if (isprint(data[i]) || isspace(data[i]))
```

Thanks anyway.

Comment: maybe using of iscntrl to check for control characters and ony then check for their codes will help. i'm not shure than == '\n' will work as you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found. This code works as desired.

```
  if (isprint(data[i]) || isspace(data[i]))
```

– Eraseth

Answer (score 0):

Since these characters ASCII values are white space you will not see them with the `"%c"` format specifier.  What you need to do is use the hexadecimal string format specifier in `printf` as follows:

`printf("%x", data[i]);`

**Note:** The `"%x"`(lowercase) and `"%X"`(uppercase) means to display the hexadecimal value of the character instead of the actual ASCII value.

I should also note, that formatting the string in this fashion will give you the raw data.  This is what it would look like in memory or what it would look like if it were transmitted on the wire. So, a `\n` would be a `0x0A` and a `\t` would be a `0x09`

See the following link for a great reference on what all the specifiers mean.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Also, here is another link to an ASCII Table.

https://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php

Hope this helps!